# Unable to check datetime condition in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I need to check condition where the datetime variable is checked with CTE parameter.

Example:

```
create table testt
(
  coldate date,
  coltime datetime,
  colseconds integer
)
```

Inserting some records:

```
insert into testt values('2014-08-02','10:00:00',50);
insert into testt values('2014-08-02','11:08:08',120);
insert into testt values('2014-08-02','11:08:55',160);
insert into testt values('2014-08-03','09:00:15',180);
insert into testt values('2014-08-04','11:00:10',600);
insert into testt values('2014-08-04','11:05:50',320);
```

CTE:

```
with t(cdate,ctime,exittime ,starttime)
as
(
   Select coldate ,coltime ,
        DATEADD(SS,colseconds ,coltime ) as CETime,
        coltime  as CSTime
   from testt
)
select exittime,starttime from t
where ctime > starttime and ctime < exittime
and cdate = '2014-08-02'
```

But when i use following query i will get result: By giving direct values

```
  with t(cdate,ctime,exittime ,starttime)
as
(
   Select coldate ,coltime ,
        DATEADD(SS,colseconds ,coltime ) as CETime,
        coltime  as CSTime
   from testt
)
select exittime,starttime from t
where ctime > '11:08:55' and ctime < '11:10:00'
and cdate = '2014-08-02'
```

Not getting how to convert it?

Comment: This question can not be understood. Please, try to re-estate. What are you trying to achieve? how? what is failing?

Comment: Your question makes no sense so far. The last query matches `ctime` against specific values whereas the previous query matches it against columns of the same dataset. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to update your last part to this?

```
select exittime,starttime from t
where ctime > '1899-12-31T11:08:55' and ctime < '1899-12-31T11:10:00'
and cdate = '2014-08-02'
```

Or you can select ctime from your db and see what kind of values are stored there. As coltime (or ctime) is datetime, a "dummy" date will be passed next to the time.

I think you will need to include that in your query to find the relevant results.